# Can't add/remove packages, post-install fails

Tags: systemd, policykit

Something is wrong with policy kit and preventing packages from starting:

```
# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.4.3-2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02nxsensor' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K02nxserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'S99pwrstatd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `rabbitmq-server' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `rabbitmq-server' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: warning: script 'pwrstatd' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'plexmediaserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: script sshINT: service sshd already provided!
insserv: warning: script 'nxserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'nxsensor' missing LSB tags and overrides
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to start rabbitmq-server.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

How can I fix this polkit gio-error-quark thing?

Even some systemctl commands give the same error:

```
# systemctl disable plymouth-quit-wait
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
```

update: it is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1447654/

Comment: All commands without `sudo`

Comment: I'm root. No need for sudo. This is implied by the traditional # PS1 instead of the $ PS1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reply to your comment yet, but have you tried the [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1447654/comments/4) mentioned in the bug thread?

> Install policykit-1 first, then reboot, then install everything else.

Comment: I would have loved for a non-reboot workaround. This server is in a difficult location for physical access and does not always boot correctly. Thanks for the help.